# Why is my video playback speed way too fast (~30x) on an external monitor?

Tags: macos, display, video

Videos I watch play back at massively increased speed when my Mac is connected to this particular external monitor.

Series played on HBO Max, for example, progress at about a 30x rate, meaning I see mostly individual frames and buffering animations (which, oddly, play at normal speed) -- it looks like videos are basically stuck in fast-forward.

Video playback is sped up across multiple browsers (Chrome, Safari), and playback of local files appears to be affected as well (the first I play a local file, it just skips to the end immediately, the second time seems fine). The issue with the playback speed of streaming video is reproducible on two entirely separate Macbooks when I connect them to this monitor, an LG 29KW600.

Unplugging the external monitor, which is connected via HDMI through a USB-C hub, instantly resolves the issue. Videos then play back at normal speed on the laptop's screen.

I've tried [killing coreaudiod](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLC7g8WB2b0) in an attempt to resolve this issue, without success.

Any insights as to what might cause this external monitor to affect video playback speed would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the [HDCP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) function of the monitor.  The fact that you can reproduce it on two different MacBooks points further in this direction.  Try it with a PC Laptop to see if it still exists.  You will want to contact the manufacturer to see if there is a resolution.

Comment: I have a similar problem with an M1 Mac and a DELL-U3219Q. It only happens when I use the Dell monitor as an audio destination, and as well as playing super fast the sound gets distorted. Doesn't happen with my work M2 Mac Pro.

Comment: Same pb, I'm pretty sure the last Macos 13.4 bring the bug. It was working normally before. 
I Originally thought it was a chrome issue, but do the same on safari. 
I have e M1 mac and have a Benq second screen. 
Also only happen when I redirect sound to the screen (where I plug my audio hears).

Comment: Same problem in 12.6.5 with an LG TV.  It isn't specific to any macOS version.  It's a bug in audio support on all LG TVs across the entire product line.  They even showed a screen when I first plugged in that I should have photographed that told what setting could interfere with audio, but they only show that message once, so I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I've tried an EDID emulator, and that doesn't help, though an HDMI splitter weirdly fixed the problem, but only at 1080p with stereo audio.  So it isn't an EDID issue.  I've also tried quitting all audio-related apps and killing and restarting coreaudiod.  No joy.

Comment: A complete reboot fixed the problem for me.  So it looks like this is yet another audio bug in macOS on ARM.  I've had constant bugs caused by the way they made the headphones and internal speakers look like two sources, weird bugs where every app that uses CoreAudio locks up hard, etc.  CoreAudio is just an absolute disaster on M1.  I'm not hopeful that macOS 14 will fix anything, given that macOS 13 didn't.

Comment: I have this problem now for the first time. Only with sound on the external monitors. M2 Max. Killing coreaudiod did not help.

Comment: Anyone found the root cause for this and how to solve it?

Comment: Exact same problem on my Macbook pro m1 with external LG TV. Only happens if I set the TV as an audio output

Comment: Same issue with a Dell U3415W monitor, so it's not specific to LG monitors.

Comment: Same problem since months, I feel that it happens when RAM usage is high but I don't have data to back this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments or upvote Alaa's response (this rep thing is dumb), but I can confirm on fully updated system which was showing the same issues all of a sudden (not had it in a year), the fix for me was as Alaa suggested.

I went into audio settings and set it back to using the in-built speakers and not sending audio out the DisplayPort, and it worked! No reboot required.

Now just got to work out why this is the case. Both my issues have been using different Macs but all with LG monitors. ‍♂️

Comment: I have the same issue and changing the settings also works for me

Answer (score -2):

use your device speaker to fix